# Two dependent dependencies from git in pubspec.yaml

Tags: git, flutter, dart

I try to fetch two dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` from git.

```
dependencies:
  chopper:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/fryette/chopper.git
      path: chopper
      ref: feature/null-safety-migration

dev_dependencies:
  chopper_generator:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/fryette/chopper.git
      path: chopper_generator
      ref: feature/null-safety-migration
```

Error:

> Because every version of chopper_generator from git depends on chopper
> from hosted and appName depends on chopper from git, chopper_generator
> from git is forbidden.

> So, because appName depends on chopper_generator from git, version solving failed.
> pub get failed (1; So, because appName depends on chopper_generator from git, version solving failed.)

**Question:** How to properly fetch two dependent dependencies?

Comment: Aren't you able to use `chopper_generator` while importing only `chopper` ?

Comment: @thomas were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @AugustinR Yes, it is not possible to use `chopper_generator` while importing only `chopper`

Comment: @PauloHenriqueNonaka you could download these two libraries into your project folder and set up properly `path`, at this moment I haven't found simpler/better way

Comment: @ThomasBanderas I could make it work using dependency_overrides for one of the two dependencies.